# Apache looks for Python 2.6 instead of 2.7

Tags: python, django, apache, centos

My OS already has Python 2.6.6 and I've installed Python 2.7.3 as an alternative. (Python's working fine). I've installed `mod_python` also, but when I try to execute a Python file on an Apache server, it shows me a list of errors where I can see it seeks to Python 2.6.6 library. But I need to work with python 2.7.3. Can anyone help me to get rid of it?

Actually I don't know if Apache is configured well or not!

I'm on CentOS 6.2.

Comment: How are you trying to deploy the python app on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome). However, note this part:

> If you want to use a different version of major/minor version of Python than currently used, you must recompile mod_wsgi against the alternate version of Python.

I'm not quite sure that if you simply swap the `WSGIPythonHome` variable it will work. If you have installed `mod_wsgi` with `yum`, you will probably have a `mod_wsgi` for `Python 2.6.x`, which is distributed with `CentOS 6.x`. If you really want to use `Python 2.7.x`, you may have to build `mod_wsgi` from source (which is actually not that hard).